# Magento2.4 enterprise cloud programatically create gift card

Tags: php, magento2.4, magento2-enterprise, gift-card

I have a phtml file in our magento2.4.4 enterprise cloud which I call via url and want to when the page is loaded programmatically generate a gift card.

My phtml file which is embedded in a cms page has the below code:

```
  <?php
      $gift_card = Mage::getModel('enterprise_giftcardaccount/giftcardaccount');
      $gift_card
            ->setCode('2i2j2j-24k1ii1')
            ->setStatus($gift_card::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->setDateExpires('2025-04-15')
            ->setWebsiteId(1)
            ->setState($gift_card::STATE_AVAILABLE)
            ->setIsRedeemable($gift_card::REDEEMABLE)
            ->setBalance(25);

      $gift_card->save();
```

?>

My issue is when I load the page I get a error that says An error has happened during application run.

Wondering if anyone has a suggestion on where the error may be in the below code?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you are using the code for Magento version 1 for Magento 2.

Assumming you place your custom php file inside the **pub** directory (`<magento directory>/pub`).

To create the gift card in the Magento enterprise cloud, you can try the following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Giftcardaccount\Model\Giftcardaccount;
use Magento\Giftcardaccount\Model\GiftcardaccountFactory;
use Magento\Giftcardaccount\Model\ResourceModel\Giftcardaccount as GiftcardaccountResource;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$giftCardAccountFactory = $objectManager->create(GiftcardaccountFactory::class);
$giftCardAccountResource = $objectManager->create(GiftcardaccountResource::class);

/** @var Giftcardaccount $giftCardAccount */
$giftCardAccount = $giftCardAccountFactory->create();
$giftCardAccount->setCode('2i2j2j-24k1ii1')
    ->setStatus(Giftcardaccount::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->setWebsiteId(1)
    ->setBalance(25)
    ->setLifetime('2025-04-15')
    ->setIsRedeemable(Giftcardaccount::REDEEMABLE);

$giftCardAccountResource->save($giftCardAccount);
```

Comment: I tried using the above code in a php file that is in app/design/frontend/mytheme/v1/Magento_Theme/templates/warranty however when I try then to run the php file I see a message that says We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.

Comment: You have placed the file in the wrong directory, as mentioned in my answer. You should place the file in the **pub** directory within your Magento root directory. Once you have done this, you can run the following command: `php pub/your_file.php` to execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

This code written in Magento1 not Magento 2 that's why getting an error

Replace the using below.

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$giftCardFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Giftcardaccount\Model\GiftcardaccountFactory');
$gift_card       = $giftCardFactory->create();

$gift_card->setCode('2i2j2j-24k1ii1')
            ->setStatus($gift_card::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->setDateExpires('2025-04-15')
            ->setWebsiteId(1)
            ->setState($gift_card::STATE_AVAILABLE)
            ->setIsRedeemable($gift_card::REDEEMABLE)
            ->setBalance(25);

      $gift_card->save();
?>
```